# CRUD Meteor accounts-ui users collection

Tags: javascript, collections, insert, meteor

Within Meteor, I'd like to insert (and other CRUD functions) data into the **users** table that is generated when one downloads the account-ui and account-password packages in Meteor. I tried creating a method to do this earlier in my client.js file:

```
Template.Something.events({
     'click .submit': function() {
          users.insert({
               type: $('.something').val()
          });
      }
})
```

When I tried I got a response that 
'users is not defined'
in my javascript console.

In addition to how to do this, I'd also like to know where the source code for the account-ui and users table actually is in Meteor 0.9.2.1.  Thank you!

Comment: It did something, the message says:

insert failed: Access denied. No allow validators set on restricted collection for method 'insert'.

What does this mean?

Comment: you need to ... let me add an answer for formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Meteor.users.allow({
  update: function(userId, user){
    // to allow update user just to user, you get it ;)? right?
    // return user._id == userId;
    // to allow all updates
    return true;
  },
  insert: function(userId, user){ /* same as above*/ }
});
```

You can put that on initialization code.

Comment: This snippet needs a comma between the `update` and `insert` methods.